# Not able to connect SQL server in Groovy

Tags: java, sql-server, selenium, groovy, workfusion

I am trying to connect to a SQL server using an automation tool (Workfusion Studio), which uses selenium and groovy.I am getting an error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" when I try to create a connection.

The code I am using is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/schema/1.0/config" scriptlang="groovy">
<selenium-flow>
<selenium name="seleniumDriver" browser="chrome" close-on-completion="true" start-in-private="true">
<script><![CDATA[
import java.sql.*;
this.class.classLoader.addURL(new URL("http://clojars.org/repo/com/microsoft/sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar"));
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER_NAME:1433;databaseName =DATABASE_NAME;";
String userName = "USER_NAME";
String password = "PASSWORD";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, userName, password);
]]></script>
</selenium> 
</selenium-flow>
</config>
```

Please help resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22No+suitable+driver+found+for+jdbc%3Asqlserver) ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect to SQL server using JAVA but not using this script.

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC connection is performed through global ClassLoader, so it does not see libs added to local ClassLoader.

You can add the driver jar globally to Control Tower tomcat:

```
$INSTALL_DIR/apps/webapps/tomcat/lib
```

For the logic to work in WorkFusion Studio, refer to the Eclipse guides on how to add external jar.

As a workaround (not recommended for production code), the following trick can be performed:

```
<script><![CDATA[
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException expected) {
        groovy.lang.GroovyShell.class.classLoader.addURL(new URL("http://clojars.org/repo/com/microsoft/sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar"));
    }
]]></script>
```

More efficient way to execute queries is as following (will properly close the DB connection, etc.):

```
<database connection="jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:6501;DatabaseName=database"
          jdbcclass="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
          username="user" password="securepassword">

    select first_name from actor
</database>
```